# Why would some kmeans clustering datapoints not be assigned to the closest centroid?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, cluster-analysis, k-means

I'm applying Kmeans clustering to my data for analysis. I've gone through the steps of scaling my code and creating the clusters, however when I look at the scatterplot matrix it appears it isn't clustering my data correctly. There are some points which are closer to centroid A but are assigned to centroid B. Any ideas? I've chosen the number of clusters to be 6 as I looked at the elbow graph and it seemed to be a good number to reduce the inertia to a good point. I chose the n_init to be 30 as my dataset is quite small and doesn't consume a lot of resources to process.

Here is my code:

```
features_to_cluster = [
    'area', 
    'perimeter', 
    'compactness', 
    'lengthOfKernel', 
    'widthOfKernel', 
    'asymmetryCoefficient',
    'lengthOfKernelGroove'
]

# features_group1 = ['area', 'perimeter', 'compactness', 'lengthOfKernel', 'widthOfKernel', 'asymmetryCoefficient', 'lengthOfKernelGroove']
features_group1 = ['widthOfKernel', 'asymmetryCoefficient']

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=6, n_init=30, init='k-means++')
df['Cluster'] = kmeans.fit_predict(df_scaled)
print(kmeans.inertia_)

df[features_to_cluster] = scaler.fit_transform(df[features_to_cluster])

df_centroids = pd.DataFrame(kmeans.cluster_centers_, columns=features_to_cluster)
df_centroids['Cluster'] = 'Centroid'
df = pd.concat([df, df_centroids], ignore_index=True)

df['Cluster'] = df['Cluster'].astype(str)

sns.pairplot(data=df, hue='Cluster', vars=features_group1)
plt.suptitle("Scatterplot Matrix - Group 1")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[Example of incorrect clustering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UjUH.png)

I tried using scaled, and unscaled data. I tried using kmeans++ and not using kmeans++. I changed the number of clusters from 2-8. I changed the n_init from 10-30. I was expecting to see clusters formed with clear boundaries.